# How to place many text elements side by side, that you see no difference between the text?

Tags: html, css

how can I place many paragraphs or div elements next to each other, that I see no difference between them? For example:

```
<div>
  <div class="text1">hey, how are</div>
  <div class="text2"> you?</div>
</div>
```

They are placed under each other, but I want them to be side by side, and please don't write me other ways, for example something like: 'you can write the text in one div'... :) I saw this question several times from other users, but they had a bit different problem like mine, so please answer me this question

Thanks

Comment: Did you try "display:inline-block"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
  <span>hey, how ar</span>
  <span> you?</span>
</div>
```

or

```
.text {
   display: inline-block;
 }

<div>
  <div class="text">hey, how are</div>
  <div class="text"> you?</div>
</div>
```

or

```
.container {
   display: flex;
 } 

<div class="container">
  <div>hey, how are</div>
  <div> you?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`div` is a block-level element, which means that it will take up the whole of a 'row' on the screen, unlike inline elements.

I'd suggest you have a read through of the MDN pages on these two categories to get a better understanding of this:

[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

[Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Among the many ways of solving this (change divs to an inline element type like `span`, using flexbox, etc), one option is to force your `div` to be inline by changing their CSS:

```css
.text1, .text2 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'll prefer display:inline-block;

Comment: Yeah, good shout. Edited suggestion from inline to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. Here I'll be showing classic ways to do this.

1. using `display:inline-block` property of css.

   ```
   .text1{
    display:inline-block; 
   }
   .text2{
     display:inline-block; 
   }
   ```
2. using `display:flex` property of css.

   html:

   ```
    <div class="text-wrapper">
     <div class="text1">hey, how are</div>
     <div class="text2"> you?</div>
    </div>
   ```

   css:

   ```
   .text-wrapper{
    display: flex;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of accomplishing this. You could do it with CSS Flexbox, CSS Grid, CSS float, or you could change the display property on the DIV's.

As you have tagged your question with "Angular", it is very common to use the Angular Flex Layout package for positioning (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout). If you add this package to your project, you could solve it like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
  <div class="text1">hey, how are</div>
  <div class="text2"> you?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: well.. angular flex layout is not recommended for more complex production. It is still beta on 9, without clear indication for actual release, and there are perfomance issues. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Performance-Considerations

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [bootsrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content)? This is a typical scenario for placing things side by side.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```